# Timestamp Assistance (Copy Paste)

Tags: timestamp

The below code works fine when I'm editing the relevant cell, however when data is pasted in the relevant cells the timestamp fails to appear...

Kindly assist

Code:

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) 
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 9 ) 
var nextCell = r.offset(0,-8);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) 
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need my 1st column to get updated with the time stamp when column 9 is filled with the data either when pasted or when entered manually

Comment: Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

Got the resolution, we need to use on event...

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sName = s.getName();
  var ar = e.range;
  var row = ar.getRow();
  var arRows = ar.getNumRows()  
  if( ar.getColumn() == 3 && sName == 'Sheet1') { 
      s.getRange(row,6,arRows).setValue(new  ate()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
```

}
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).